# What does gc-interval in named sets actually do?

Tags: linux-networking, nftables

I'm testing out named sets in my nftables ruleset but I can't find any explanation of what the `gc-interval` parameter actually does.

The documentation simply states:

> Garbage collection interval, only available when *timeout* or *flag
>   timeout* are active.

But what exactly does garbage collection mean in this context?

A wiki [example](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Port_knocking_example) uses it like so:

```
set example {
  type ipv4_addr
  flags timeout
  timeout 10s
  gc-interval 4s
}
```

So what does the `gc-interval 4s` do in relation to the `timeout 10s`?